# Automatically updating QSqlTableModel and QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, auto-update, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I have created a model using `QSqlTableModel`, then created a tablview using `QTableView` and set the model on it.

I want to update the model and view automatically whenever the database is updated by another program. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no signal emitted for that currently. You could use a timer to query the last update timestamp and refresh the model data at designated intervals.